# Specific pattern matching in Regex in Javascript

Tags: javascript, regex

I want to use regex to match the string of the following format :
(`#sometext#`)

In the sense ,whatever is there between (`#` and `#`) only should be matched.
So, the text:

```
var s = "hello(%npm%)hi";
var res = s.split(/(\([^()]*\))/);
alert(res[0]);
o/p: hello(%npm%)hi
```

And

```
var s = "hello(#npm#)hi";
var res = s.split(/(\([^()]*\))/);
alert(res[0]);
o/p: hello
alert(res[1]);
o/p : (#npm#);
```

But the thing is , the regex `/(\([^()]*\))/` is matching everything between `()` rather than extracting the string including `(# .. #)`
like:

```
hello
(#npm#)
hi
```

Comment: You can do something like `s.match(/\(#([^#]*)#\)/)` if you don't need the parts outside the parentheses. (Why are you using `.split()`? If you really want to do that then maybe something like `s.split(/(\(#|#\))/)`?)

Comment: @nnnnnn: I have edited the question

Comment: Try this:s.match(/(\(#([^#]*)#\))/);

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By going in your way of fetching content, try this:

```js
var s = "hello(%npm%)hi";
var res = s.split(/\(%(.*?)%\)/);
alert(res[1]);
//o/p: hello(%npm%)hi

var s = "hello(#npm#)hi";
    var res = s.split(/(\(#.*?#\))/);
console.log(res);
    

//hello, (#npm#), hi
```

From your comment, updated the second portion, you get your segments in res array:

```
[
  "hello",
  "(#npm#)",
  "hi"
]
```

Comment: I need the output as : hello,
(#npm#),
hi                  for the second example

Answer (score 1):

The following pattern is going to give the required output:

```
var s = "hello(#&yu()#$@8#)hi";
var res = s.split(/(\(#.*#\))/);
console.log(res);
```

"." matches everything between (# and #)

Answer (score 0):

It depends if you have multiple matches per string.

```js
// like this if there is only 1 match per text
var text = "some text #goes#";
var matches = text.match(/#([^#]+)#/);
console.log(matches[1]);


// like this if there is multiple matches per text
var text2 = "some text #goes# and #here# more";
var matches = text2.match(/#[^#]+#/g).map(function (e){
  // strip the extra #'s
  return e.match(/#([^#]+)#/)[1];
});

console.log(matches);
```